# Extracting a match from a string with sed and a regular expression in bash

Tags: regex, bash, sed

In bash, I want to get the name of the last folder in a folder path.

For instance, given `../parent/child/`, I want "child" as the output.

In a language other than bash, this regex works `.*\/(.*)\/$` [works](https://regex101.com/r/pJ6aFy/1).

Here's one of my attempts in bash:

```
echo "../parent/child/" | sed "s_.*/\(.*?\)/$_\1_p"
```

This gives me the error:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 17: unterminated `s' command
```

What have I failed to understand?

Comment: `basename "../parent/child/"`?

Comment: Replace `FOO` with your regex in this GNU sed command: `echo '../parent/child/' | sed -E 's/FOO/\1/'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem with your script is that inside the `"s_.*/\(.*?\)/$_\1_p"` the `$_` is interpreted by the shell as a variable name.
You could either replace the double-quotes with single-quotes or escape the `$`.

Once that's fixed, the `.*?` may or may not work with your implementation of `sed`. It will be more robust to write something roughly equivalent that's more widely supported, for example:

```
sed -e 's_.*/\([^/]*\)/$_\1_'
```

Note that I dropped the `p` flag of `sed` to avoid printing the result twice.

Finally, a much simpler solution will be to use the `basedir` command.

```
$ basename ../parent/child/
child
```

Finally, a native Bash solution is also possible using parameter expansion:

```
path=../parent/child/
path=${path%/}
path=${path##*/}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use cut too

```
echo '../parent/child/' | cut -d/ -f3
```